# How do I output sequences in an array of numbers (int) in java?

Tags: java

For example I have this array:

```
int[] a = {1,1,1,1,5,5,1,1,1};
//output: 4 2 3
```

In other words, it will print the sequences of the same number.
I have already tried this:

```
int doubles_count_while (int a[][], int n, int cestatic) { 
    int result = 1; 
    while (result < n && a[result - 1][cestatic] == a[result][cestatic]) {
        result++; 
    }
    return result;
}

int doubles_groups(int a[][], int n, int cestatic, int b[]) { 
    int result = 0; 
    int i = 0; 
    while (i  < n) {
        int z = doubles_count_while(a, n-i, a[i][cestatic]); 
        b[result++] = z; i += z; 
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. In what way does your code not yet yield the correct result?

Comment: If your input is supposed to be an `int[]`, why do your methods take an `int[][]`? I mean, if your method doesn't even accept the type of data you're supposed to process, how could you ever except it to be useful?

Answer (score 2):

When posting code, please post it as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can actually run it. You should also tell us **what you expect this code to do** and **what it does instead**. Try to narrow it down to a single line of code that's not doing what you expect it to do.

This is a pretty broad question, but I'll try to help in a general sense. You need to take a step back and forget about the code for a second. Write down the steps **you** would follow, without a computer, if somebody handed you a stack of index cards with numbers written on them and asked you to group them. How exactly would you do that?

Pretend you have a really dumb friend who has no idea how to group the cards. You should be able to hand your instructions to that friend and have them follow them to group the cards without any help from you. Remember how dumb this friend is, so make sure your instructions are as small as possible.

When you have those instructions written out, that's an algorithm that you can start thinking about implementing with code. Trying to dive into the code without a clear idea of what you want it to do is just going to give you a ton of headaches. Good luck.